# Recommended wind screen for MEMS microphones

Tags: noise, microphone

Some folks in  my lab are using Wildlife Acoustics Song Meter Mini sensors in a very windy grassland environment and having recordings get messed up by wind noise. Has anybody here had good luck with wind screens for these MEMS mics (or the similar ones on Audiomoths)  especially with very high wind speeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a good option would be a lavalier mic windscreen. Various manufacturers produce this, like:

BubbleBee: https://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/bubblebee-windbubble-l01-mini-windshield-for-lavalier-microphones-28mm.html

Rycote: https://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/rycote-lavalier-windjammers-pair.html

https://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/rycote-baby-ball-gag-windshield-various-sizes.html

These would fit over the foam windscreen already provided with the SMmini.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom windscreen to cover the whole microphone. Something like this:
https://www.dodotronic.com/product/windscreen-for-hi-sound-mono/

Answer (score 3):

Wildlife Acoustics recommends using an extra foam cover over the mics.  This helps some.  Furries can be problematic, as birds attack and steal them.